# Migrate AWSDate to AWSDateTime

Tags: amazon-web-services, graphql, amazon-dynamodb, aws-appsync

Good morning,

currently I use the AWSDate Scalar Type. I have 75000 database items that now have to use AWSDateTime Scalar type.

Is there someone with a smooth solution how to migrate the items in the database because for now I getting an AppSync/graphQL error:

```
  "errors": [
    {
      "path": [
        "getItemsByAlbum",
        "items",
        1,
        "shootDate"
      ],
      "locations": null,
      "message": "Can't serialize value (/getItemsByAlbum/items[1]/shootDate) : Unable to serialize `2022-11-07` as a valid DateTime Object."
    }
  ]
```

So I know, that out of the box the `AWSDate` is not compatible to `AWSDateTime` but maybe someone knows about a smooth easy solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

75k items should be quite easily modified using a simple script from Lambda.

`Scan` your table to retrieve the items, and for each item retrieved, modify it's timestamp attribute and call `UpdateItem`.

To give you an example on the timing, I updated 1M items on one of my tables in under 2 minutes.

Comment: Seems to be lightning fast :) Thanks.

Thought about that, but was not sure about the speed :)